# createObjectURL blob url not secure in Chrome

Tags: javascript

Your connection to this site is not secure while navigating to window.URL.createObjectURL(blob) in Https Site

I am doing

```
window.location.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
```

to get below in new tab:

> blob:https://***.***.***.**/392d72e4-4481-4843-b0d4-a753421c0433

Getting issue: Your connection to this site is not secure.

Analysis: CSP whitelist (e.g. navigate-to ?) needs to be done but don't exactly know how since we are not setting any header there.

Any help will be appreciated ! Thanks !

[image]

Comment: could you please elaborate? you want chrome not to show this message on navigating to your link ? right?

Comment: yup, correct !!

Comment: this message is because of SSL cretficate. you can obtain the certficate for this.

Comment: _“Analysis: CSP whitelist (e.g. navigate-to ?) needs to be done”_ - says who? I don’t see anyone complaining about an actual issue with restricted navigation here.

Comment: @04FS: This is what i found till now ( might be wrong as well ). I want to get rid of that warning.

Comment: Then I’d suggest you start by presenting a proper [mre] that shows the issue.